# Dynamically change connectionstring

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I'm having a problem where I want to dynamically change a part of my connectionstring in my Web.config file.
Everywhere I've looked people are saying it is the wrong to place to store it then, but I cannot find anywhere else to put this.

The idea is that I'm connecting to a database and I have to specify the SQL Client. My ASP.net site should be accessible from many different computers, and they have different SQL Clients. `Eg. SQL Server Native Client 10.0` or `SQL Server Native Client 11.0`.

I've found a way to retrieve this data as a string, but i cannot figure out how to insert it into my ConnectionString.

An example of my connection string is as follows:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="name" connectionString="DRIVER=SQL Server Native Client 11.0;server=server;Database=database;Trusted_Connection=Yes; Provider=SQLNCLI11.0" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I want to replace the Provider field `SQLNCLI11.0` with the string I've managed to create.

Comment: Where does your ASP.net site run - on a single server, or on dozens of clients?

Comment: Mutilple clients

Comment: `Provider`/`Driver` are not relevant if your using `SqlClient` btw.

Comment: Driver is not longer relevant. It's something still there from the past. Not that i'm using an OleDbConnection, i need Provider.

Comment: So your connecting to non SQL Server databases as well?  Just make the config value `Provider={PROV}` then create a helper method that returns it after replacing `{PROV}` with the correct provider string?

Comment: That is what i want, but i don't know how to insert anything into the web.config connectionString. It is read only so you cannot insert like this: `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["name"].ConnectionString = "something";`

Comment: Why does it need to be "dynamic" - by which I assume you mean at run time - can you not set this at installation time? When you deploy the ASP.Net app, presumably there's an installation script which can modify the connection strings?

Comment: I meant along the lines of `var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["name"].ConnectionStr‌​ing.Replace("{PROV}", YourMethodToGetProviderNameString());`

Comment: did you get to the bottom of this ? it will be great if you can update your findings here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not clear why you would like to dynamically change your connection string when you can have multiple connection strings in config and read them on run time.
You can follow these steps:
 1. Declare multiple connection strings in your config file like this :

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="Provider1" connectionString="..." />
<add name="Provider2" connectionString="..." />
</connectionStrings>
```

2. As you said

> I've found a way to retrieve this data as a string, but i cannot
>   figure out how to insert it into my ConnectionString.

Use provider name to access connection strings like this :

```
string  Provider1Connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Provider1"].ConnectionString;
string  Provider2Connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Provider2"].ConnectionString;
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

You can set connection string as environment variable or on secret manager.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets